# Start and end date of previous quarter in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I am trying to figure out how to get the start and end date of the previous quarter. For example:

1. Jan 2nd, 2020 - The output should be 20191001, 20191231
2. July 27th, 2020 - The output should be 20200401, 20200630

Thanks in advance for all the help and guidance.

Answer (score 4):

```perl
use DateTime qw( );

my $prev_quarter_start = 
   DateTime
   ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
   ->set_time_zone('floating')     # Use this when dealing with dates.
   ->truncate( to => 'quarter' )
   ->subtract( months => 3 );

my $prev_quarter_end =
   $prev_quarter_start 
   ->clone
   ->add( months => 3 )
   ->subtract( days => 1 );

say $prev_quarter_start ->ymd('');
say $prev_quarter_end->ymd('');
```

Requires DateTime 1.32.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for your help. I am getting this error though

The 'to' parameter ("quarter") to DateTime::truncate did not pass regex check
 at /cs/eqtyctrl/sw/perl/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/x86_64-linux/DateTime.pm line 1975.

Comment: @SreeniH, The code I posted was tested. `quarter` was added over four years ago in version 1.32. In earlier versions, you could truncate to `month`, then use `$dt->set_month( int( ( $dt->month - 1 ) / 4 ) + 1 );`